# XSLT - Create a node from another context

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file:

```
<config>
    <files>
        <file uuid="uuid-file1">
            <name>File1</name>
        </file>
        <file uuid="uuid-file2">
            <name>File2</name>
        </file>
        <file uuid="uuid-file3">
            <name>File3</name>
        </file>
        <file uuid="uuid-file4">
            <name>File3</name>
        </file>
    </files>
    <folders>
        <folder uuid="root" />
        <folder uuid="folder1">
            <member ref="uuid-file1" />
        </folder>
        <folder uuid="folder2">
            <member ref="uuid-file2" />
        </folder>
    </folders>
</config>
```

ie = file1 is referenced into folder1 and file2 is referenced into folder2.
file3 and file4 are not in a folder.

My problem:

I would create a XSLT transformation to browse all "files" and create a reference in folder "root" for them which are not referenced in a folder.

Example (file3 and file4 are not in a folder):

```
<config>
    <files>
        <file uuid="uuid-file1">
            <name>File1</name>
        </file>
        <file uuid="uuid-file2">
            <name>File2</name>
        </file>
        <file uuid="uuid-file3">
            <name>File3</name>
        </file>
        <file uuid="uuid-file4">
            <name>File4</name>
        </file>
    </files>
    <folders>
        <folder uuid="root" >
            <member ref="uuid-file3" />
            <member ref="uuid-file4" />
        </folder>
        <folder uuid="folder1">
            <member ref="uuid-file1" />
        </folder>
        <folder uuid="folder2">
            <member ref="uuid-file2" />
        </folder>
    </folders>
</config>
```

I try to do it with 'for-each' loop but I don't know how create a new node in folder 'root' when I browse "files" node...

I need your help :-)

Regards,
Zido

Comment: can you show the XSLT that you try? and the problem with it? It will be more likely getting help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="folder" match="folder" use="member/@ref" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="folder[@uuid='root']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="/config/files/file[not(key('folder', @uuid))]">
            <member ref="{@uuid}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes we know how to identify the "root" folder (in this example by its `@uuid` value being literally the string "root"). This part of your question it's not quite clear.

Comment: Right: folder "root" is identified by its uuid which is equal to 'root'.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. I just added <xsl:apply-templates/> to copy the whole tree.

Comment: @zido71 The *identity transform* template "copies the whole tree".